# run maven exec-maven-plugin as last step

Tags: maven-2, maven

I want to execute a command line script with exec-maven-plugin after "mvn test"  How do I set this up under pom.xml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just take the example from the project website and have to add a phase to the execution. I've just tested with this pom below and it works fine.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>q5110133</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Test.bat</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>c:\temp\test.bat</executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>C:\temp</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: you should use `<phase>test</phase>` (at least that's what the OP's after)

Comment: @Sean Patrick: Well probably _install_ wasn't the best choice for an example. It was just a phase I knew that would hit :-) I've changed that.

Comment: This works, but I have a "next step" question: what if the "test.bat" of the example above is able to produce a "JUnit XML report" file? How do I give it back to Maven? Any idea/example?

Comment: @Detro: That depends on what you want to do with it - generally speaking you can use files from the target folder in the build process. Perhaps it's best to ask this as a question of its own so that others will find it, too.

Comment: For me the correct step was install when I wanted to run something after jar was created. Works perfectly. Thanks for sharing full `pom.xml` for newbies like me.

Answer (score 8):

The point of the ordering is, that you have to choose a phase for execution, which is behind the test-phase. You can see this in the Maven Build Lifecycle.

For example, you could use prepare-package which is the phase directly after the test phase.

BTW: Plugins, when configured in the same lifecycle, are executed in the order in which they are listed in the pom.xml.