# Java maven project one time jobs plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying do migration in my java project. I could find schema migration but certain complex migration need a script to be executed. Is there a maven repository plugin which can be used to execute scripted migration I.e. one time job?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "migration"? Could you give an example?

Comment: Data migration. Either it could be schema migration, or change the values in a column. Now I have to change the pre-existing values to the new one. Db migration tool such a liquibase are hard to use when the migration logic depends on more than one factor, in that case I need scripts to be executed to normalize the changes in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a build tool, I would not use Maven to run one-time jobs. Each action configured within a Maven build would be executed each time the build is running.

There are multiple options to start scripts or trigger complex actions when a Maven build is running. Some of them are

- [Ant-Run-Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html): triggers any [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) task
- [Groovy-Plugin](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute.html): calls a [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) script
- [Exec-Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html): calls an external program. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181226/2129801) for details how to bind this plugin to a lifecycle phase

You can probably find a Maven plugin for most of the usual scripting languages.